# Where should I put an if function for my Guessing game?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

Right now, I am working on Chapter 3 of the book Python for the absolute beginner.

One of the challenges at the end of chapter 3 is to "Modify the Guess My Number game so that the player has a limited number of guesses" and that if the player fails to get the correct amount of guesses, a message should be displayed.

The code looks like this:

```
# Guess My Number
# The computer picks a random number between 1 and 100
# The player tries to guess it and the computer lets
# the player know if the guess is too high, too low
# or right on the money

import random  

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n")

# set the initial values
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
tries = 1

# guessing loop
while guess != the_number:
    if guess > the_number:
        print("Lower...")
    else:
        print("Higher...")
            
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1

print("You guessed it!  The number was", the_number)
print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")
  
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

From what I can see so far, I need to add a variable that counts how many lives a player has, which is set to an amount at the beginning, like 10 and an if command should be used to make sure that, when the player uses all their lives, the message is displayed.

However, I am unsure where to place the if command in the existing code.

Answer (score 3):

Well, If I were you I would make a game loop instead of the guessing loop. And then I would just break the game loop when I reach the guessing limit. However if you wanna keep your code you can use this.

```
while guess != the_number:
    if tries == 3: # Replace 3 with the limit you'd like to use
        print("You lost :(")
        exit()
    else:
        if guess > the_number:
            print("Lower...")
        else:
            print("Higher...")
        
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1
```

Also in your case don't use break, it will still cause to print in the end the winning msg

(the spacing might be a little bit off so u may need to fix it)

Comment: Personally, I find it a bit weird that when tries haven't been exceeded, some of the code is in the else and some of it isn't - I'd move the code out of the else block so that what you're left with is a guard clause. I think this would be clearer, although obviously that is subjective.

Comment: I'm not talking at all about performance (I think there would be no difference), I'm only talking about how easy to read the code is.

Answer (score 1):

After you say `tries+=1`, put an if statement. Your code should look like this:

```
if tries>3:
    print("Game Over")
    break()
```

Comment: if my answer helped you, please mark the green checkmark and upvote so it can help the community.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment about break (which, by the way is a statement, not a function) because I realised that it wasn't sufficient - firstly, you can get a game over message even if your last guess was correct, and secondly you'll get a "you guessed it!" message even if you didn't

Answer (score 0):

```
import random  

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n")

# set the initial values
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
tries = 1

while tries < 8:
    if guess == the_number:
        print("You guessed it!  The number was", the_number)
        print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")
        break
    elif guess > the_number:
        print("Lower...")
    else:
        print("Higher...")
            
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1

if tries == 8:
    print("You failed to guess my number")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

You can also do it this way